# Returning values and statements from functions

Tags: rascal

I am wondering about the difference in behaviour between using the `return` statement and defining a function with the pattern `foo() = Expression`

It's my understanding from: [Funtions](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/Function/Function.html) that a function body can be `= Expression` and `return` takes either nothing or an `Expression`

The reason I am asking is that by my understanding of the documentation the following shouldn't work:

```
map[int,int] foo(map[int,int] env) = env[0] = 1;
```

Which it doesn't (causing a parse error) since assignment is a `Statement`. However, if I slightly modify this function:

```
map[int,int] foo(map[int,int] env) { return env[0] = 1; }
```

This seems to work. I am confused because I though `return` should only take expressions. Also, it looks like from playing around on the REPL this assignment returns a `Value` so it would be nice be able to define functions that assign and return the modified map.

Maybe I am missing something here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is fine. The return statement has some extra flexibility though to allow returning the value produced by selected statement kinds such as 'for' and assignment apparently too. See the syntax definition of the return statement in the Rascal grammar [here](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/rascal/syntax/Rascal.rsc#L611)

In future versions we may remove all restrictions and allow statements everywhere.